# Show image into DataGridView display Bitmap string instead image

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a `DataGridView` and I want to use a column to display image from image list so I do this on my `CellFormattingEvent`

Code:

```
private void dgvUpload_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgvUpload.Rows)
    {
        var backColor = row.Cells["BackgroundColor"].Value.ToString();

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(backColor))
        {

            switch (backColor)
            {
                case "#52451C":
                    row.Cells["BackgroundColor"].Value = imageList1.Images[0];
                    break;
                case "#0F4C1D":
                    row.Cells["BackgroundColor"].Value = imageList1.Images[1];
                    break;
                case "#8E1A1C":
                    row.Cells["BackgroundColor"].Value = imageList1.Images[2];
                    break;

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Problem is instead show image it throws Bitmap string as:

[image]

What am I doing wrong? regards

**Update**

As comments bellow, I'm adding it from database... So I have a list of model then I assign it as a DataSource:

Model:

```
 public class MessageModel
    {
        public string Tab { get; set; }
        public string Message { get; set; }
        public bool Uploaded { get; set; }
        public string BackgroundColor { get; set; }
    }
```

ModelList:

```
   public List<MessageModel> MessageList { get; set; } = new List<MessageModel>();
```

Then I assign it to DataSource as:

```
   dgvUpload.DataSource = null;
   dgvUpload.DataSource = superTemplateLogic.MessageList;
```

**Update 2**

As last comments bellow I change my code. First I remove `CellFomratting` event and try to create  new image column then assign value depending of message, now `BackgroundColor` return 3 values "success, warning and Fail"

So depending of each one I get the image and assign to this new column and at the end I remove BackgroundColor column:

```
 var messageList = superTemplateLogic.MessageList.ToDataTable();
            dgvUpload.DataSource = null;
            dgvUpload.DataSource = messageList;

            DataGridViewImageColumn imageCol = new DataGridViewImageColumn();
            imageCol.Name = "Status";
            imageCol.DisplayIndex = dgvUpload.Columns["BackgroundColor"].DisplayIndex + 1;

            dgvUpload.Columns.Add(imageCol);


            for (int index = 0; index < messageList.Rows.Count; index++)
            {
                var currentStatus = messageList.Rows[index]["BackgroundColor"];
                var image = imageList1.Images[0];

                switch (currentStatus)
                {
                    case "success":
                        image = imageList1.Images[0];
                        break;
                    case "warning":
                        image = imageList1.Images[1];
                        break;
                    case "fail":
                        image = imageList1.Images[1];
                        break;
                }


                dgvUpload.Rows[index].Cells["Status"].Value =  image;
            }
        messageList.Columns.Remove("BackgroundColor");
```

Now I have a column with no images, it just display "x":
[image]

Comment: The “BackgroundColor” column appears to be a `DataGridViewTextBoxColumn`, I would guess you want a `DataGridViewImageColumn`.

Comment: How can I change column to `DataGridViewImageColumn`? @JohnG

Comment: How is the column currently added to the grid? If you added the column from the designer, then change the column type in the designer. If you are getting the column from a data base, then it would appear that column is not an image column, possibly a string path. In that case it will require more work, as you would need to add the column in the designer or code. As I started, how are you adding the current column?

Comment: I'm adding it from database, I update my question with details of how I do it @JohnG

Comment: There appears to be conflict in your code. As the line of code `var backColor = row.Cells["BackgroundColor"].Value.ToString();` “implies” that the cells already have values. In this case `string` values. Therefore, later in the code, it appears you want to “change” that columns type to an “image” type. `row.Cells["BackgroundColor"].Value = imageList1.Images[0];` ? … The column cannot be both types at the same time.

Comment: Since the “BackgroundColor” property in the `MessageModel` class is a `string` type, then that property will become a “TextBox” column in the grid and NOT an “image” column. You are going to have to “add” the Image column in the designer or code. Then set each cells image value (from the image list) based on the value of the “BackgroundColor” cell for each row.

Comment: Ok, now I do a 360 change to my code based in your comments, can you check my update in my question please @JohnG

Comment: From a glance, the code appears correct. Have you stepped through the code to make sure it falls into one of the case sections? The case values look different than the original code. Previously the case was "#52451C", now its “Success”? Did the data change in the database? Are you sure the image list contains images?

Comment: Yes, I changed "#52451C" to success, and I'm sure my list have items, I debug code and all the values are correct, the image is correct and cell too, but that is the result @JohnG

Comment: It is difficult to say what could be the problem. I suggest trying to put the images into another control like a `PictueBox` to validate that the images display properly. If the images display properly, then remove the condition that checks for the “BackgroundColor” and simply add the same image to all rows. If needed, make a new project with just the image column and add the images. This is debugging 101, isolate the problem.